# Load an excel file which is in a different language to a gridview. Then save it to a oracle DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oracle

My requirement is to load an excel file which has the content in, lets say Chinese, to a gridview. 
Then user will have look at the loaded content, then he will have to save the data to a oracle table.
And later on they should be viewed in the same language.

Can some one tell me how I can save the data to the DB and then display in the same language.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I need a way to save the data to the DB, then display them in the same language.

Comment: be more specific... the data needs to be editable, searchable, etc. any requirements? there are 50 ways to do what you need

Comment: I receive an excel file containing customer contact details in Chinese along with the SSN which contains 12 digits and an English letter. Only the name, address and the branches they are attached to is in Chinese. Joining with other tables will be done using the SSN. Searches will be done by the SSN. And the data should be editable at any point. Apart from displaying in ASP.NET pages, the data should be printed in pdfs (itextsharp) as well.